# TYPO3 redirect showAction to another page

Tags: typo3, action, show, fluid, extbase

i want to redirect my single article to a page where i add my plugin and select a single view. I read about switchable controller actions. But now they are deprecated. This is my method

```
/**
 * action show
 *
 * @param Article $article
 * @return ResponseInterface
 */
public function showAction(Article $article): ResponseInterface
{
    $this->view->assign('article', $article);
    return $this->htmlResponse();
}
```

How can i redirect to a page where my plugin is included and the setting "single" is set?

I've tried

```
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'KNews',
    'News',
    [
        \Kubus\KubusNews\Controller\ArticleController::class => 'list',
        \Kubus\KubusNews\Controller\CategoryController::class => 'list'
    ],
    // non-cacheable actions
    [
        \Kubus\KubusNews\Controller\ArticleController::class => '',
        \Kubus\KubusNews\Controller\CategoryController::class => ''
    ]
);
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'KNews',
    'News',
    [
        \Vendor\KNews\Controller\ArticleController::class => 'show',
        \Vendor\KNews\Controller\CategoryController::class => 'list'
    ],
    // non-cacheable actions
    [
        \Vendor\KNews\Controller\ArticleController::class => 'show',
        \Kubus\KNews\Controller\CategoryController::class => ''
    ]
);
```

and

```
<f:link.page pageUid="{settings.detailPage}" additionalParams="{article : article}">{article.title}</f:link.page>
```

but then i wont get to the show action

Answer (score 1):

The [deprecation notice](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/10.3/Deprecation-89463-SwitchableControllerActions.html#migration) informs about a migration:

> **Migration**
>
> Unfortunately, an automatic migration is not possible. As switchable
> controller actions allowed to override the whole configuration of
> allowed controllers and actions, the only way to migrate is to create
> dedicated plugins for each former switchable controller actions
> configuration entry.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> <switchableControllerActions>
>    <TCEforms>
>       <label>switchable controller actions</label>
>       <config>
>          <renderType>selectSingle</renderType>
>          <items>
>             <numIndex index="1">
>                <numIndex index="0">List</numIndex>
>                <numIndex index="1">Product->list</numIndex>
>             </numIndex>
>             <numIndex index="2">
>                <numIndex index="0">Show</numIndex>
>                <numIndex index="1">Product->show</numIndex>
>             </numIndex>
>          </items>
>       </config>
>    </TCEforms>
> </switchableControllerActions>
> ```
>
> This configuration would lead to the creation configuration of two
> different plugins like this:
>
> ```
> \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
>     'extension',
>     'list',
>     [
>         'Product' => 'list'
>     ]
> );
>
> \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
>     'extension',
>     'show',
>     [
>         'Product' => 'show'
>     ]
> );
> ```

Comment: And how can i then redirect to another page?

Comment: That information can't be resolved automatically by the extension. It has to be given in any kind (via `<f:link... pageUid="123"..>` in your list-template. Or you define some kind of `settings.detailPid` via FlexForm/TypoScript for a more flexible way.

Comment: Ok thank you. Do i have to name them really list and show or could it be the same name but with different actions? I have to rewrite the whole extension if i have to give new names

Comment: No 'list'/'show' in this example are only names. From docs "With the second argument, a unique name called plugin name is given for the plugin (also in UpperCamelCase notation and with less than 32 characters). The plugin name is used to identify the plugin clearly." ( https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/main/en-us/4-FirstExtension/7-configuring-the-plugin.html#configuring-the-plugin )

Comment: I just write `<f:link.action pageUid="{settings.detailPage}" controller="Article" action="show" arguments="{article : article}">{article.title}</f:link.action>` instead of `<f:link.action action="show" arguments="{article : article}">{article.title}</f:link.action>` an this works to. Is this a wrong solution?